# SignalR - "Connection was disconnected before invocation result was received" exception

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

Developing my first SignalR prototype for demo to my company.

Issue I'm running into when attempting to call server function, 'GetChatUsers,' is that when I call the method via JS, I get an exception, 'Connection was disconnected before invocation result was received,' immediately after the server executes the 'Return' of the 'ChatUser. object.

I am using a synchronous call to the method, and I have stepped through the request to insure there is an IEnumerable object being returned.  Once the server actually passes off to the client, the client enters the '.fail' method of the method call and the exception is displayed.  I'm not sure why this is happening, but I have built the server side and clientside logic similar to how the request for 'GetAllStocks' is built here... http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-server

Here is my server code...

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs;
using UMARepository.DataModels;

namespace UMAChatHub.Service
{
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public IEnumerable<ChatUsers> GetChatUsers()
        {
            return UMARepository.Service.ChatService.GetChatUsers();
        } 
    }
}
```

JS/JQuery...

```
var getChatUsers = function () {
    var umaChatHubProxy = $.connection.chatHub;
    umaChatHubProxy.connection.start().done(function() {
        umaChatHubProxy.server.getChatUsers().done(function(users) {
            $.each(users, function() {
                console(this.firstName);
            });
        }).fail(function(ex) {
            console(ex.message);
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer finally hit me like a ton of bricks.

The exception, "Connection was disconnected before invocation result was received," occurred because I was attempting to return an Entity Data object, rather than a POCO object.

I fixed this by creating a DTO, and using Automapper to map from the Entity to the DTO object.  I returned that object rather than the Entity object and the error no longer occurs.

Comment: does this not work: return UMARepository.Service.ChatService.GetChatUsers().ToList();

Comment: I'm thinking that returning an entity set should not be a problem if the query has been executed before the return attempt. Strange, unless the return call results in references being crawled in the returned type.

Comment: it's worth noting that this should still worki n the event that you do "dbContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
dbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;" to turn off the lazy loading / proxy types in EF ... but after testing this I found it doesn't

Comment: @Wardy no, return UMARepository.Service.ChatService.GetChatUsers().ToList(); does not work, because that's exactly what the ChatService is returning. An IEnumerable list, which then bubbles up to our SignalR return, which acts as a pass through, returning, IEnumerable<ChatUsers>.

Comment: Thats not what i meant ... IEnumerable<T> is a perfectly valid object to give to signalr,  however if the underlying type T is an ef proxy or the IEnumerable is say a DBSet<T> then signalR will fail to serialize the result as it will effectively try to crawl your DB. Having a List<T> wont fail because what is there is there and it can't get any more data by crawling references. The only exception would be recursive references "Item1.Item2.Item1". Your problem is either recursion or the use of proxying / lazy loading, take all of those out and it will "just work".

Comment: That said your answer is still correct though in that good practise tells us don't give the front end an entity ... ever! use a proper n-tier approach and all will become easy :)

Comment: As Wardy said, it's because signalrR failed to serialize, in this case entity object. i think it's because of recersive reference between entities in EF

Comment: I think you mean, "recursive."